# Apache 2.4 directory listing

Tags: apache, ubuntu

This is nightmare!

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with Apache 2.4

I have configured pgAdmin4 and now I want to configure Apache to allow download files from location "web" i.e.: http://x.x.x.x/web/myfile.py
and this is giving error 404.
I have added sites-available/web.conf, enabled this site (now I can see came on sites-enabled) and my web.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot /var/www

      <Directory /var/www>
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

files is located at /var/www/web/myfile.py

pgAdmin4 is configured on http://x.x.x.x/

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of your .py file. They should be 755.

Also add the following in the virtual host directive:

```
<Files *.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
```